# running apache on fedora/selinux/no setroubleshoot messages on desktop

Tags: selinux

I have installed fedora 24 installed from scratch via iso image.

I have httpd started and can see the default page if I access "localhost".

Now I want to add a directory which should contain files for download. I
simply added these files to the new directory like:

```
/var/www/html/tar-packages/
```

I tried to access from browser: "localhost/tar-packages"

apache error log:

> [Mon Jun 27 18:28:57.903136 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 24823] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:53204] AH01275: Can't open directory for index: /var/www/html/tar-packages/

OK, the file permissions and httpd.conf is fine. I have a look in selinux:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1467044937.902:1659): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=24823 comm="httpd" name="tar-packages" dev="dm-0" ino=1453837 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

OK, the problem is related to selinux.

But now I am wondering!

Q: Why I got no alert message on my desktop and how can I configure that? On fedora 23 there comes up a little message box with a simple info which selinux command I can enter to get the problem fixed. How can I enable this tool on my new fedora 24 system?

BTW: If someone can also fix the access problem on my http server is also fine.

But more important is to get the alert messages again on my desktop system. It was really helpful for the older fedora distributions.

Answer (score 1):

try running `# restorecon -rv /var/ww/`

Comment: Thanks, that's enabled my new path in the apache config, but the important part of my question "how to enable the pop up messages" are still open...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic, httpd in a desktop environment is hardly an on-topic question here. Maybe in superuser you will have more luck with your linux desktop question